# SceneKit - Draw scaling Circles with an equal line width at any scale

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit, scnnode

I want to draw scaling animated circles with SceneKit. The circles shall change their radius from (maybe) 100 to 200 in a second. One can only see the outline of the circle with a width of (random value) five.

I draw the circles with SCNShape and UIBezierPath. Scaling the circles doesn't help as then the outline width changes as well. Changing the SCNGeometry proprty of my SCNNode every frame is very very costly and I get 100% CPU usage from that, so this also doesn't really work.

Does anybody have an idea what the best way is?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of options here. Test and profile some to see which gives you the best tradeoff between the visual effect you want and performance.

#### 1. Use a particle system

Drawing hundreds of circles per second sounds a lot like a [particle system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticleSystem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNParticleSystem), particularly if their placement follows a specific pattern. Set the `particleImage` to a bitmap of a circle (with sufficiently high resolution that you don't get pixelation upon scaling), and use a [property controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticlePropertyController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNParticlePropertyController) to animate the size.

#### 2. BYO particle system

If `SCNParticleSystem` doesn't fit the bill, you can do roughly what it does — draw billboarded sprites and adjust their size. Use an `SCNLookAtConstraint` to face a plane toward the viewer, map a circle texture onto it, and animate the `scale` of the containing node.

#### 3. Use a parametric geometry

Make an `SCNCylinder` or `SCNSphere` and transform it so that the circular cross section is oriented toward the camera. (Flatten it in other dimensions if that matters.) To make it grow, animate the node's `scale`.

To show only an outline, use a shader modifier — a good way to get an outline effect in shader code is to test the dot product of the view direction and the surface normal, drawing your outline color only when they are nearly perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer! Version 3 sounds best for me....but will it also work if I want to use 2D circles / SCNShape with an extrusionDepth of zero? The normals are always pointing towards the camera then. Especially when using orthographic projection.

Comment: I think I could manage drawing an outline by calculating the pseudo distance (via squares) of each fragment to the center...but that's not really super cool and I hope there's something better.

Comment: I just tried your idea with the sphere....but it leads to weird results unfortunately. It's not that weird if thinking more about it....as the 2D perspective might come after the outline calculation. But maybe I also made a mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late to the party, but there's another nice way using SCNGeometrySource and SCNGeometryElement.

1. Generate vertices
2. Generate texture coordinates
3. Generate indices
4. Set material (image, solid colour etc)
5. Animate the scale from 100 to 200

I made a gist of a class I made incase it's useful to anyone else.

https://gist.github.com/kemalenver/79523e5606f62c5958fcf5e9bedc48a5